# Trying to extend WiFI using a trendnet tew-818dru AC1900Ghz router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, repeater

First, I have a Comcast router on 10.0.0.1 - it's a gigabit connection and assigns IPs up to .253. I have a slightly old TrendNet [tew-818dru](https://www.trendnet.com/products/wifi/AC-routers/AC1900/TEW-818DRU) AC1900 router that I wanted to add as a wireless AP or repeater to fill in some dead spots in my house. So, I logged into the old router at 192.168.10.1 and started making changes - matched the SSID and Key to the Comcast router, checked gateway and then went to Advanced LAN to disable DHCP and assign a static IP. Can do everything up to assign the IP - changed it to 10.0.0.254 and hit Apply and it just spins and spins. Eventually, I get tired of waiting and try the new IP - won't let me in using original IP or the new IP. Tried this 5-6 times after hard reset with same results. Sure would like to know what I'm doing wrong. Just for giggles, I changed the IP to 192.168.10.254 without any problem! Is there something about totally changing subnets I don't know? Like is it hardwired to only accept 192.168.10 subnet IPs? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you consider a different approach? If all you want is _a better signal over there_ there's an app for that... Make a signal reflector to mount on your WiFi antennae https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-WIFI-Antenna-Reception-Booster/ to boost the gain in a particular direction with cereal box cardboard, tape, and aluminum foil.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a three level house - it's not just a matter of directing the signal outward to a corner of the house - it's 'down'. Eventually, my plan is to have the primary Comcast router and 'two' repeaters to extend the signal or boost the signal on each floor. Don't get me wrong - there's signal on each floor now - but, I have a gig coming in and I get about 180 in the deep recesses of the basement :) Don't yell at me! Many would be happy with 180 - but, hey, I'm paying for a gig - I should get better than 180 - I'm shooting for 300-400 throughout the house!

Comment: Make sure you are connecting a LAN port (not WAN) on the Trendnet Router to a LAN port on your main network. Then log into the Trendnet interface and give it a Static IP on your network. Make sure DHCP is OFF (as you did) and it should connect.  Then second, consider a secondary Ubiquiti access point to extend wireless range if needed

Comment: What's the make and model of the Comcast gateway box?

Comment: Since I've done this before, I knew to connect to a LAN port and not the WAN. Just changing the LAN IP address to a static IP is just not working. The more I think about it, the more I realize there are other things that have to be changed - possibly even the WAN IP. I'm adding an IP to a router in the 192.168.10.x subnet - the IP I'm adding is in the 10.0.0.x subnet - there are other settings on the 192 router that are locked into that subnet - aren't there? Like maybe I really need to change the WAN IP into the 10 subnet first since that's the same subnet as the Comcast router.

Comment: My Comcast router is the newest they have - it's a gigabit Xfinity X1 router.